# How to display original image height and width using xsl-fo?

Tags: xls, xsl-fo

In my case,
I have to display image on pdf as original height and width.
original means same the image height and width.

i have used,

```
<fo:external-graphic src="url({$optionImageSrc})"  scaling="uniform" content-height="scale-to-fit">
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work, exactly?

Try using `content-height='100%' content-width='100%'`.
If you use `scale-to-fit`, the image will be scaled to fit within the surrounding block.

Comment: Of course you do know an image can exist without an "original" width and height. Some images have assumed sizes and their size in XSL FO will be scaled to whatever the XSL FO engine assumes it could be. Some use 92dpi, others use 120dpi. In that case, you have no "correct" answer because neither one of those is wrong and both are different.